# Vertical align fractions

Tags: vertical-alignment

Is it possible to align two formulas in two lines inside a case block, that are not of the same lenght? For example, I have these two formulas and I would like to align vertically the left hand part before `=` and align the two fractions on the right hand part in order to occupy the same space.

```
\begin{cases}
E_{\theta}=\dfrac{num}{denom}\dfrac{very long num}{shorter denom}  \\ 
E_{\phi}=\dfrac{longer num}{denom}\dfrac{1}{long denom}
\end{cases}
```

Comment: What do you mean by “occupy the same space”?

Comment: Are you asking how to align the invidual `\dfrac` expressions? Please advise.

Comment: Exactly, the two formulas are composed by two `\dfrac`and I'd like that the two are vertically aligned the one to the other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions. Both make use of `array` environments. The upper solution centers both pairs of fractional terms vertically. The lower solution right-aligns the first pair of terms and left-aligns the second pair. Note that `\times` directives have been inserted to make sure that the readers understands how the fractional terms in a given row are supposed to be associated with each other.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,amsmath}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\displaystyle}c}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\displaystyle}l}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\displaystyle}r}
\newcolumntype{z}{>{{}}c<{{}}} % for mathbin & mathrel operators
\begin{document}

\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}

\[
\left\{
\begin{array}{RzCzC}
E_{\theta}&=&\frac{\text{num}}{\text{denom}}&\times&
           \frac{\text{very very long num}}{\text{shorter denom}}  \\[2ex]
E_{\phi}  &=&\frac{\text{longer num}}{\text{denom}}&\times&
         \frac{1}{\text{long denom}}
\end{array}
\right.
\]

\[
\left\{
\begin{array}{RzRzL}
E_{\theta}&=&\frac{\text{num}}{\text{denom}}&\times&
           \frac{\text{very very long num}}{\text{shorter denom}}  \\[2ex]
E_{\phi}  &=&\frac{\text{longer num}}{\text{denom}}&\times&
         \frac{1}{\text{long denom}}
\end{array}
\right.
\]
\end{document}
```